# Am I using Bootstrap's navbar correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find any info how the intended implementation of [Bootstraps](http://getbootstrap.com/) `navbar` is suppose to be done.

Right now I have downloaded the [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), and cloned it for each of the button options, changed the menu so the shows the correct selected button, but this can't hardly be the correct way, as it is a lot of copy/paste maintenance.

Also I am guessing that is not the intended method, as it [looks like](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) `navbar` is a class in bootstrap.

Has anyone tried to use `navbar` and can tell me how they did it, or point me to the intended method?

Comment: did you check this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4. This is a really good video about using the bootstrap navbar

Comment: @Deep Yes, it doesn't really tell me, how to implement it, which led me to the copy/paste method where I have cloned the page for the each menu button. I would think Bootstrap have to JS/JQuery to modify the DOM when a menu button is pressed?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: paste your code what you have done and tell us what difficulty you are facing

Comment: @Vinc199789 Very nice video. I hadn't seen it before. He touches on the `class=active`, which is the one that high lights the selected menu button. How do you move this without having to clone the entire page again? I suppose this have to be done on server-side?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes I don't use bootstrap anymore but waht you can do is changing the active by javascript. In Jquery it is: `.removeClass()` and `addCLass()` But indeed it is a very usefull video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is outside of Bootstrap's scope how to implement it in an efficient way. That is the job of a server-side language.

When you have a situation where you do a huge copy/paste, then think template, and for small copy/paste think variable like in the case of the menu, where you have to change the active state.

Any modern server-side language have a template engine, where you put in skeleton of your page.

For the menu, you probably want to generate it, where you have the menu button names in a yaml file or perhaps database of some sort.

On the other hand is it popular to offline generate all possible html pages, and then serve them with a plain httpd or nginx. [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) are such examples.